# STDIN or file as mapper input in Hadoop environment?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

As we need to read in bunch of files to mapper, in non-Hadoop 
environment, I use `os.walk(dir)` and `file=open(path, mode)` to read in 
each file.

However, in Hadoop environment, as I read that HadoopStreaming convert 
file input to stdin of mapper and conver stdout of reducer to file 
output, I have a few questions about how to input file:

1. Do we have to set input from STDIN in mapper.py and let 
   HadoopStreaming convert files in hdfs input directory to STDIN?
2. If I want to read in each file separately and parse each line, how 
   can I set input from file in mapper.py?

My previous Python code for non-Hadoop environment sets: 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path of non-hdfs') 
  .....

However, in Hadoop environment, I need to change 'path of non-hdfs' to 
a path of HDFS where I copyFromLocal to, but I tried many with no 
success, such as `os.walk('/user/hadoop/in')` -- this is what I checked 
by running bin/hadoop dfs -ls, and `os.walk('home/hadoop/files')`--this 
is my local path in non-Hadoop environment, and even `os.walk('hdfs:// 
host:fs_port/user/hadoop/in')`....

Can anyone tell me whether I can input from file by using file 
operation in mapper.py or I have to input from STDIN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop streaming **has** to take input from STDIN. I think the confusion you're having is you're trying to write code to do some of the things that Hadoop Streaming is doing for you. I did that when I first started Hadooping.

Hadoop streaming can read in multiple files and even multiple zipped files which it then parses, one line at a time, into the STDIN of your mapper. This is a helpful abstraction because you then write your mapper to be file name/location independent. You can then use your mappers and reducers for any input which is handy later. Plus you don't want your mapper trying to grab files because you have no way of knowing how many mappers you will have later. If files were coded into the mapper, then if a single mapper failed you would never get output from the files hard coded in that mapper. So let Hadoop do the file management and have your code be as generic as possible.

Comment: Hi @JD Long , I have many csv files in hdfs directory, I want to read all the csv files from the directory, can you suggest how can I do this. I am confuse d what to do. As I did script for test on locally read csv files from directory. If I run it on server it works on input streaming so, I am getting exception to read the files (streaming command failed). I am new with python for hadoop, so I dont know how to do. Please suggest how can I do it

Comment: what have you tried? Take a look at this and then try to hack something up. If you hit snags, form it into a StackOverflow question. Then repeat the process: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/